# How to test a Step Tracker

Tags: ios, testing, accelerometer

I am developing an application that counts step and calories burned for iOS (based on steps taken).This app is likely similar to pedometers available in the market.

I want to test its accuracy, is there a simulator or tool, that will help me to test its accuracy?

Thanks

Comment: You could probably use the Shake Gesture (^⌘Z) in the iOS Simulator to simulate motion. 

To gauge the accuracy, you're better off running it on a real device and compare it to at least two pedometers worn at the same time. Test it in a variety of scenarios: horizontal motion, uphill, downhill, stairs, etc.

Comment: thanks @neilco if I install it in my device, are you aware of any tool, app i can use to see if it is accurately counting my steps and computing my calories burned?

Comment: I'm not aware of any apps—I suggest you search the App Store. Like I said, you are probably better off comparing your app's results to those of a real pedometer or two.

Answer (score 0):

You can use apple health kit to compare the steps accuracy. If you are using the accelerometer for calculating steps you can't get the actual steps. It is better to use cremation framework if you want to track the steps, distance or calories accurately.

Also always use a real device to test.